# Cannot create a third fieldset in a form

Tags: html, fieldset

I cannot create beyond 2 fieldsets in a the HTML form. The code seems correct. It works for the first one and the second one but the third `<fieldset>` does not appear.

Here is my code:

```html
<body>
  <h1>Please Enter Your Details</h1>

  <form method="post" action="destination">

    <fieldset>
      <legend>Your face</legend>
      <label for="Your Image">Your Image</label>
      <input type="File" id="Your Image">
      <img id="preview" src="" alt="">
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <legend>Your General Details</legend>
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Your Full Name">
      <br>Gender:
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">Male
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Female
      <br>
      <label for="age">Age:</label>
      <input type="number" id="age" placeholder="18">
      <br>Date of Birth:
      <input type="date" name="birthdate">
      <br>Favorite color:
      <input type="color" name="color">
      <br>Which Country:
      <select name="country">
        <option value="">
          <option value="USA">USA</option>
          <option value="UK">United Kingdom</option>
          <option value="France">France</option>
          <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
          <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
          <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <legend>Your Indications</legend>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: An element `id`, and therefore a `for` attribute, cannot contain white-space, and you never closed your `<select>` element. Other than that, though, I can't see why this wouldn't work.

Comment: With a few notable exceptions, you should always "close what you open", one very common way to be able to visualise what needs to be closed is by using indentation, don't be lazy and think it's a waste of time, start indenting today.

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem user?

Answer (score 0):

[This plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/L9CFLQFltFjqPylE8fb0?p=preview) shows that you forgot to put an end tag to your select tag in your second fieldset.

```
<select name="country">
 <option value=""></option>
 <option value="USA">USA</option>
 <option value="UK">United Kingdom</option>
 <option value="France">France</option>
 <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
 <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
 <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

you are missing a option tag this should work give it a try

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body><h1>Please Enter Your Details</h1>

<form method="post" action="destination"> 

<fieldset>
<legend>Your face</legend>
<label for="Your Image">Your Image</label>
<input type="File" id="Your Image">
<img src="" id="preview"  alt="" />
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend>Your General Details</legend>
<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Your Full Name">
<br>
Gender:
 <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">Male
 <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Female<br>
 <label for="age">Age:</label>
 <input type="number" id="age" placeholder="18">
 <br>
 Date of Birth:
 <input type="date" name="birthdate"><br>
 Favorite color:
 <input type="color" name="color"><br>
 Which Country:
 <select name="country">
 <option value=""></option>
 <option value="USA">USA</option>
 <option value="UK">United Kingdom</option>
  <option value="France">France</option>
  <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
  <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
   <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
  </select>
 </fieldset>

 <fieldset>
 <legend>Your Indications</legend>
 </fieldset>
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Yep you were right. I simple oversight the html editor didn't flag. Thanks a bunch. :)